# How could this pic show in this unexpected way with networkx in GCN?

Tags: python, pytorch

[the pic of the dataset called KarateClub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQVRq.png)
It's the example of [PYG](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1h3-vJGRVloF5zStxL5I0rSy4ZUPNsjy8?usp=sharing#scrollTo=etxOsz8QIbMO)

```
main.py

from torch_geometric.datasets import KarateClub
from torch_geometric.utils import to_networkx
from visualize import visualize_graph
import torch

# Load the dataset
dataset = KarateClub()
data = dataset[0]
print(data)

# Visualize the graph

edge_index = data.edge_index
G = to_networkx(data, to_undirected=True)
visualize_graph(G, color=data.y)

---------------------------------
visualize.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx


def visualize_graph(G, color):
    plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G, seed=42), with_labels=False,
                     node_color=color, cmap="Set2")
    plt.show()


def visualize_embedding(h, color, epoch=None, loss=None):
    plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    h = h.detach().cpu().numpy()
    plt.scatter(h[:, 0], h[:, 1], s=140, c=color, cmap="Set2")
    if epoch is not None and loss is not None:
        plt.xlabel(f"Epoch:{epoch},Loss:{loss.item():.4f}", fontsize=16)
    plt.show()
```

I have the same codes with the [PYG](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1h3-vJGRVloF5zStxL5I0rSy4ZUPNsjy8?usp=sharing#scrollTo=etxOsz8QIbMO) example, but the pic show in unexpected way, the normal way is :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGfaR.png)